# Using Firebase autogenerated key to return post specific data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to retrieve from Firebase a post's specific location which places a marker on the map where that location is (Latitude and Longitude). I have to do this by querying the autogenerated key that Firebase creates because each post has it's specific autogenerated Firebase key.

I looked up how to query a Firebase key and I am doing it like this `String key = snapshot.getKey();`. But it isn't returning just one location, it's returning all of the locations that have been saved to Firebase.

I should only get one location when clicking on a specific post and that post and location should be found via the Firebase autogenerated key.

Can someone explain what needs to be changed in my code?

I just added an alternative to my code. Could someone indicate if that would be a better alternative to the first code.

[image]

**MapsActivityUser.java**

```
public class MapsActivityUser extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    String postid;
    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_user);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        postid = preferences.getString("postid", "none");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;

        final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String key = snapshot.getKey();
                    if (snapshot.hasChild("location")) {
                        Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                        if (post != null) {
                            double latitude = post.getLocation().getLatitude();
                            double longitude = post.getLocation().getLongitude();

                            LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Event location"));
                            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 10));
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivityUser.this, "Event doesn't have location on Map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Option Two** Here I compare the `postid` to `post.getPostid();`. If they match up then marker is placed on the map for that post's location and all the other ones are removed. Bottom line is only ONE marker should always be on map, not more than one. And it should reflect *that* post's location and non other.

```
final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key = snapshot.getKey();
            Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
            if (post != null) {
                if (post.getPostid().equals(postid)) {
                    double latitude = post.getLocation().getLatitude();
                    double longitude = post.getLocation().getLongitude();

                    LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    mMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Event location"));
                    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 10));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivityUser.this, "Deleting Markers", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                //Code to remove all markers that don't have that postid
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: you didn't put `postid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you have `postid`, you can go either way:

**Option - 1:** Directly access `location` with the help of `postid`

```
reference.child(postid).child("location").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        double latitude = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
        double longitude = dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);

        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

**Option - 2:** Access `location` by retrieving **Post** with the help of `postid`

```
reference.child(postid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
        if (post != null) {
            double latitude = post.getLocation().getLatitude();
            double longitude = post.getLocation().getLongitude();

            ....
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: @JMB, Have you checked that?

Comment: It's not working... I think my SharedPreferences is wrong. When I Log it I get a postid that doesn't reflect any of the ones that I have in the database... I don't know why I am getting this postid...

Comment: That's a different problem. Please pick any `postid` as hard coded  from database and run the code to check whether it's work or not

Comment: But this one doesn't exist... This one it is returning but it's not in my database. I will try with one of the other ones that I have

Comment: If I hardcode the postid it works! The only problem now is my postid in SharedPreferences is wrong?

Comment: Please add another question with details where you add the `postid` to `SharedPreferences `

Comment: I did it by mistake. It's good now

Answer (score 1):

You missed here `postid`

```
reference.child(postid).child("location").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
        if (post != null) {
            double latitude = post.getLocation().getLatitude();
            double longitude = post.getLocation().getLongitude();
            LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Event location"));
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 10));
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivityUser.this, "Event doesn't have location on Map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It doesn't return anything. The map comes back blank, no markers...

Comment: @JMB updated answer. try again

Comment: It just goes to the Toast message now. Still no marker for post's location on Map

Comment: I still just get the Toast message... Can you tell me if the code I just posted would be a better alternative for getting the post's location. I compare the ```postid``` to ```post.getPostid();``` and if it matches up a marker is placed on the map and all the other ones are removed.

Comment: @JMB you don't have to compare with all the `postid` because you already has value for specific Post already. can you confirm the value `postid` is correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207064/discussion-between-jmb-and-ticherhaz).

Comment: your answer is correct the only thing is my SharedPreferences are wrong because when I hard code the postid it works. Retrieves location just as it should!